# Does Leave One Out cross validation increase the chance of overfitting?

Tags: cross-validation, overfitting

By increasing the size of the training set the model memorize more data. Thus, will using leave one out increase the chance of overfitting?

Answer (score 1):

ML model will start to "memorize" data with increasing complexity of your algorithm (and its parameters), not the size of training set.

Cross-validation is used to estimate your model performance on data that was not used to train. If you use *LOOCV (k=n)* then your *k* models 
will be (almost) identical. This gives you a **high variance** in your model evaluation and **low bias** regarding the final model trained on the
entire data set.

Use *10-times 10-fold stratified CV* if you unsure about a good value for *k*.

Comment: The part about high variance is not always true and is an incorrect generalization of a special case for unstable algorithms - see recent posts about bias variance trade-off around the site